# Context Menu visibility in TableView JavaFX

Tags: java, contextmenu, tableview, javafx-2, javafx

I am creating `TableView` in JavaFX. In which I want to show `Context Menu` in right click of mouse in tableView. So I am adding an EventHandler on table as given below :

```
    TableView tableView=new TableView();

    EventHandler event = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
            if (me.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                tableView.getContextMenu().show(tableView, me.getSceneX(), me.getSceneY());
            }
        }
    };
    tableView.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event);
```

But my problem is that `Context Menu` is visible wherever I right click on any part of table.

I want to do that `Context Menu` should be only visible if I clicked on any rows in `TableView`.

i.e. How would I get row number in TableView at specific point, So that my `Context Menu` should be only visible, if I clicked on any row of `TableView`.

Comment: Dub of [How to get row number in TableView at specific point?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13930961/682495). I see tableView.getContextMenu() so other somewhere you are setting the contextmenu. If you set it, it will always be shown even you don't add event handler explicitly. I mean if you want to control the showing of contextmenu don't set it through tableView.setContextMenu(), IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I found was to check if the y coordinate is outside of the bounds of the column header and then to explicitly show the menu.

```
ContextMenu visibleMenu = null;
tableView.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {
    if (visibleMenu !=null) {
        visibleMenu.hide();
        visibleMenu = null;
    }
    if (e.getButton()==MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
        double columnHeaderHeight = tableView.lookup(".column-header-background").getBoundsInLocal().getHeight();
        if (e.getY()>columnHeaderHeight) {
            visibleMenu = getContextMenu(); // build on the fly or use a prebuild menu
            visibleMenu.show(tableView, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY());
        } else {
            // you could show a header specific context menu here
        }
    }
});
```

The added benefit is that you can build the context menu on the fly with context sensitive items (that for example only appear if a certain type of cell is selected), or just reuse a prebuild contextmenu as setContextMenu does, up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Add context menu to the specific cells using `CellFactory` not to the whole table.

E.g. using Table from [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm):

```
    TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn();
    firstNameCol.setText("First");
    firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("firstName"));
firstNameCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {
    @Override
    public TableCell call(final TableColumn param) {

        final TableCell cell = new TableCell() {

            @Override
            public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    if (isEditing()) {
                        setText(null);
                    } else {
                        setText(getItem().toString());
                        setGraphic(null);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        // This way I will have context menu only for specific column
        cell.setContextMenu(ContextMenuBuilder.create().items(MenuItemBuilder.create().text("menu").build()).build());
        return cell;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

may be the older question. There is a solution, like getting the target of the mouse event of the table and check for instance for class TableCellSkin and display the context menu as,

```
table.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,
                new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                        if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY
                                && !isRowEmpty) {
                            EventTarget target = e.getTarget();
                            if (target instanceof TableCellSkin
                                    || ((Node) target).getParent() instanceof TableCellSkin) {
                                    // do your stuff. Context menu will be displayed by default
                            } else {
                                // hide the context menu when click event is outside table row
                                table.getContextMenu().hide();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@FXML
void tableContextMenuRequested(ContextMenuEvent event) {
    if (tableview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().size() == 0) {
        tableContextMenu.hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Submit this method to tableview's onContextMenuRequested action. tableview is your tableview's fx:id, tableContextMenu is tableview's context menu fx:id

Comment: please add details/clarifications to your answer (_not_ as a comment)